# TS:2304 cannot find Jasmine definitions in WebStorm 2017.3 with Angular CLI

Tags: typescript, jasmine, angular-cli, webstorm, definition

Angular by default has included `@types/jasmine`.  Moreover, the types are include in the `tsconfig.spec.ts`

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

W/O the definitions I can still click into the definition files which is weird:

[image]

[image]

My `describe` will only work if I reference the path directly which is bad practice:

```
///<reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts"/>
// Now works!

describe('Service: Auth', () => {

});
```

**Question:** Any idea why my types for Jasmine are not being visually referenced in WebStorm?

Comment: how did you solve this issue? ``tsconfig.json`` already has ``typeRoots`` with ``"node_modules/@types"``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebStorm does not support `tsconfig.spec.json`. All the TypeScript options should be described in the file named `tsconfig.json`. Please follow this related issue for updates: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28091

Comment: That was it! :)